# Hibernate deletes a record, but the record doesn't go away?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

EDIT:  Oops, I guess it would help if I posted the delete code.  Sorry.

```
    // delete from permanent store and local list
    int index = get_record_to_delete();
    if (entityList.getEntities().get(index).getEntityId() != null ) {
        // existing persisted record
        entityService.delete(entityInfo.getEntities().get(index).getEntityId());
    }
    //remove from local list
    entityList.getEntities().remove(index);
    return ownersInfo;



    // entityService called by above code
    public void delete(MyEntity entity)  {
        repository.delete(entity);  // subclass of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
    }
```

I'm using Spring Data/JPA V 1.4.2.RELEASE and hibernate 3.6.10.Final.

I have a situation where I'm deleting an entity, and delete appears to work, but when I refresh my web page, the entity reappears.  So, it doesn't produce an error, but the record doesn't get deleted.

This entity has child entities contained within it.   I suspect that some kind of entity dependence problem is keeping the entity from being truly "deleted", but I don't know which entity dependency it might be, and Hibernate's not telling me.  It doesn't matter if the contained entities get deleted or not, but this entity needs to get deleted.   Not sure why that's not happening.    Here's the entity I'm trying to delete:

```
public class MyEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "MYID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long myId;

    @Column(name = "MY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String myName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private AddressEntity myAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OTHER_ADDRESS_ID", nullable = true)
    private AddressEntity myOtherAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_CODE", nullable = false)
    private MyType myType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_CODE", nullable = false)
    private AddressCode addressCode;

    @Column(name = "OTHER", nullable = false, precision = 3, scale = 0)
    private Integer myOther;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private MyParent parent;

    @Column(name = "PHONE", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    private Long myPhone;

    @Column(name = "SOCIAL", nullable = false, length = 9)
    private String mySocial;
}
```

Anyone see anything that might suggest why this entity won't delete?

Comment: how are you trying to delete the entity? Please Post the delete part of the code.

Comment: Show us where you actually do the delete please.

Comment: Most common problem is you didn't commit the delete, but we can't know for sure until you post the code.

Comment: That indeed appears to be the problem. Use `flush()` to make sure the delete is committed.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan: flush() and commit() are very different things. By default, a commit() always calls flush() before committing.

Comment: is the transaction management correct?

Comment: My mistake, @JBNizet, you are correct.

Comment: It looks like this may be related, not to the child entities, but to the PARENT entity of the one that I'm trying to delete.   Hibernate walks through everything at flush time and because the property in the parent has 'cascade=CascadeType.ALL' set on it, it cancels the delete.   I'm still investigating and trying to figure out the reasoning there....

Comment: @JBNizet of course you made an important note: flush and commit are different things, but the idea to flush is not bad (although it does not commit): flushing will tell you whether you have an active transaction or not (no matter how a transaction was opened).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This turned out to be a case of a Hibernate @OneToMany annotation canceling the delete.

Because the parent object had a `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` annotation on it, like this:

```
Class MyParent {

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<MyObject> myObjects;

}
```

Hibernate apparently walks the entire object graph and for some reason, because this **parent** wasn't being deleted, it canceled the **child** delete.

The thing to do to detect this is turn your logging all the way up to `TRACE` and look for the following message from Hibernate:

```
un-scheduling entity deletion
```

Those are the magic words that let you know that Hibernate is canceling your delete.  This was not particularly well documented, so I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: what you want to do, is specify `orphan-removal=true` that way if you remove the child from `myObjects` it will automatically be deleted when you save the parent.

Comment: This worked for me, I changed @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) to @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval=true)

Answer (score -2):

In your mapping class use this cascade type. It will delete the records from database.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```