# Hibernate entityManager not deleting object even after flush/refresh

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernates entityManager to delete an object. However the object is not getting deleted even after flushing the entityManager. It is getting returned if I do a `find` on it using is id.

Following is what my piece of code looks like:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "registryPU")
private EntityManager em;

public <E> E delete(Class<E> clazz, String id) {
    E en=(E) find(clazz, id);

    if(en != null){
        em.remove(en);
        em.flush();
    }

    en=(E) find(clazz, id);
    assert ( en == null);

    return en;
} 

public <E> E find(Class<E> clazz, String id) {
    return em.find(clazz, id);
}
```

and the persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="registryPU"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql"/>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

This should ideally work fine, but is throwing `java.lang.AssertionError` because of the assert statement. Can someone let me know what is wrong in this and how to avoid it ?

Comment: Are you sure that the transaction is not being rolled back somehow?  Can you also post the code where you get the reference to the `EntityManager` ?

Comment: I dont see the transaction getting rolled back. I haved added the reference to entityManager and the persistence.xml

Comment: Just curious. Why `find` method is not called on `em` object?

Comment: @wawek Sharp eye, and the code for `find()` should be included in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Added `find()`. Hope this anwers your question @wawek

Comment: I probably should have asked this earlier, but if you run your code, does the object actually get deleted from the corresponding database table, or is the record still present?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261067/hibernate-deletes-a-record-but-the-record-doesnt-go-away) and its correct answer - most probably your entity is being referenced by another loaded entity and hibernate then won't delete the object from database. When you turn on TRACE logging of hibernate, you should see a message `un-scheduling entity deletion`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this after remove(), but before flush()

```
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I am using `transaction-type="JTA"` and hance cannot use this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see `<jta-data-source>` entry in your `persistence.xml`. Try adding it as below:

```
<persistence-unit name="registryPU"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql"/>
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: I am using `transaction-type="JTA"` and hance cannot use this.

Comment: Updated the answer, adding `<jta-data-source>`.

Comment: That didn't help. I am still getting the exception i.e. A `JTA EntityManager can not use the EntityTransaction API.  See JPA 1.0 section 5.5`

Comment: It's because `em.getTransaction()` can not be used while using JTA EntityManager, trying removing it.